# Suddently cannot connect to mysql: ERROR 2003 (HY000)

Tags: mysql, windows

This might be a duplicate but most of the answers found did not solve my issue.

I have had mysql(mariadb) installed and working for the last six month.

A few days age I've a made another account on my PC for work purposes and have shared my PHP/MySql/Apache folder with the user.
For the first week it was working perfectly but today suddently when trying to log in to mysql with `mysql -u root` I get:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061 "Unknown error")

- I have checked services.msc and mysql is fine and running.
- `net stat mysql` gives me **System error 5 has occurred. Access is denied.**
- My system "path" variables are correct, even running the cmd in `../mysql/bin` does not work
- Running my cmd as Admin on the "work" account

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer by following the [MariaDB install: I unchecked running as service during installation. What is correct way to start and stop mariadb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29067887/mariadb-install-i-unchecked-running-as-service-during-installation-what-is-cor#29068284)

After running the three commands I noticed that on my main account if now have an option to **start** the service again. 
Starting it solved the issue